# difference between two dates in azure ml

Tags: python, pandas, azure

I am trying to find difference between two dates in terms of number of days. I am trying the following code

```
d1=pd.to_datetime(dataframe1['Order Date'])
d=str(d1)
dates=datetime.strptime(d,'%m-%d-%Y')
d2=pd.to_datetime(dataframe1['Dispatch Date'])
dd=str(d2)
dates1=datetime.strptime(dd,'%m-%d-%Y')
dataframe1['Months_difference']=dates1-dates
```

But it's being displaying the error like this:

> ValueError: time data '0    2017-02-13\n1    2017-02-24\n2    2017-03-02\n3    2017-03-06\n4    2017-03-06\n5    2017-03-06\n6    2017-03-11\n7    2017-03-23\n8    2017-03-23\n9    2017-03-24\n10   2017-04-07\n11   2017-04-07\n12   2017-04-07\n13   2017-04-07\n14   2017-04-07\n...\n855   2018-02-02\n856   2018-02-02\n857   2018-02-02\n858   2018-02-02\n859   2018-02-02\n860   2018-02-01\n861   2018-02-06\n862   2018-03-15\n863   2018-03-21\n864   2018-03-21\n865   2018-04-05\n866   2018-04-07\n867   2018-04-07\n868   2018-04-11\n869   2018-04-10\nName: Order Date, Length: 870, dtype: datetime64[ns]' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y'
>   Process returned with non-zero exit code 1
>   How to solve this

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do this all from within `pandas`, without the datetime module. I'm assuming your starting dataframe looks something like:

```
>>> dataframe1
  Dispatch Date  Order Date
0    2017-03-02  2017-02-13
1    2017-03-06  2017-02-24
```

In which case, you can do:

```
# set columns to datetime:
dataframe1['Order Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe1['Order Date'])
dataframe1['Dispatch Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe1['Dispatch Date'])
# Make a new column for the difference in days
dataframe1['day_diff'] =  dataframe1['Dispatch Date'] - dataframe1['Order Date']
```

Which outputs:

```
>>> df
  Dispatch Date Order Date day_diff
0    2017-03-02 2017-02-13  17 days
1    2017-03-06 2017-02-24  10 days
```

**Explanation**: subtracting two datetime objects in `pandas` results in a [`Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html) object (as in the new column `day_diff`). If you want it as an integer reprsentation of the number of days, just add `dt.days` to that last command:

```
dataframe1['day_diff'] =  (dataframe1['Dispatch Date'] - dataframe1['Order Date']).dt.days
```

Comment: raise NotImplementedError('Python Bridge conversion table not implemented for type [{0}]'.format(value.getType()))
NotImplementedError: Python Bridge conversion table not implemented for type [<type 'numpy.timedelta64'>]
Process returned with non-zero exit code 1

Comment: Could you post the first few rows from your dataframe in your question as an edit?

Comment: Order Date Order No_ Product Item No_ Quantity Unit Price With out Tax Unit Price with Tax With Out Tax With Tax Amt Dispatch Date Finished Date Due Date
2/25/2013 0:00 EFF/SAL/12-13/471 RTU 47300 1 6779.66 8000 6779.66 8000 6/7/2017 0:00 6/6/2017 0:00 9/7/2017 0:00

Comment: THis is the first row of my dataset